# TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA and SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Tags: tomcat, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, catalina

Is there any difference between these cipher suites? They look the same however the first three letters are different.

I am referring to TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA and SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA.

Comment: These are not certificates, but cipher suites. Check the values of the constants.

Comment: Also see Thomas Pornin's answer to [How did SSLv3 get AES?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61549/how-did-sslv3-get-aes). on the [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IANA maintains a registry of TLS cipher suites at [TLS Parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#table-tls-parameters-4). In SSL/TLS, cipher suites are specified by 2 octets.

`TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` uses `0x00,0x2F` and its specified in [RFC 3268, AES Ciphersuites for TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3268). It supplemented the cipher suites from the original [The TLS Protocol Version 1.0](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt) of RFC 2246. [RFC 5246, The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) included it out of the box.

There is no `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` per IANA. Its not listed in the draft [The SSL Protocol Version 3.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-ssl-version3-00). And its not listed in [RFC 6101, The Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) Protocol Version 3.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101) either. I suspect its a synonym or alias used by some libraries after RFC 3268.

Related: SSL protocols are *not* under IETF control. See, for example, [RFC 5746, Section 4.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746#section-4.5):

> While SSLv3 is not a protocol under IETF change control (see [SSLv3]),
> it was the original basis for TLS and most TLS implementations also
> support SSLv3.

OpenSSL *does* provide `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` - its called `AES128-SHA` in the cipher suite list. OpenSSL *does not* provide `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`. See the [`ciphers(1)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html) documentation.

Below, both a TLSv1 and SSLv3 connections are made with `AES128-SHA`.

```
$ openssl s_client -tls1 -connect google.com:443 -cipher "AES128-SHA"
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
...
```

And

```
$ openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect google.com:443 -cipher "AES128-SHA"
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
...
```

My guess is `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` was added to SSLv3 around the time RFC 3268 was published. But I can't find a document covering it.

In either case, the primitves are the same: `RSA` key transport, `AES` block cipher, `CBC` mode, `SHA` HAMC, etc. The only difference is the protocol (SSLv3 vs. TLS 1.0 and friends).